# How to Use Multiple IF Conditions in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to store multiple values in different SESSIONS for that I have multiple If conditions in VB Code that works fine

```
If roleRow.Item("Code").ToString() = "101" Then 'Admin Settings
    If roleRow.Item("Active") = True Then Session("101") = True Else Session("101") = False
End If
If roleRow.Item("Code").ToString() = "102" Then 'Summaries / Reports
    If roleRow.Item("Active") = True Then Session("102") = True Else Session("102") = False
End If
If roleRow.Item("Code").ToString() = "103" Then 'Invoices List
    If roleRow.Item("Active") = True Then Session("103") = True Else Session("103") = False
End If
```

but the same code structure doesn't work in C#.

It evaluates only the first IF condition and rest conditions it shows the same value as first IF condition. Any suggestions how to solve this?

```
private void UserPermissions_Read()
{             
    BOL.Master.UsersRoles aDA = new BOL.Master.UsersRoles();
    DAL.Master.UsersRoles.UsersRolesDataTable aDT = new 
    DAL.Master.UsersRoles.UsersRolesDataTable();
    aDT = aDA.Read("1", 1, "", 1, "", "", "", "");
    DataRow dRow;
    if (aDT.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dRow = aDT.Rows[0];              
        if (dRow["Code"].ToString() == "101" && (Boolean)dRow["Active"] == true)
        {
            Session["101"] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Session["101"] = false;
        }               
        if (dRow["Code"].ToString() == "102" && (Boolean)dRow["Active"] == true)
        {
            Session["102"] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Session["102"] = false;
        }                
    } 
    else 
    {
        Session["101"] = false;
        Session["102"] = false;
        Session["103"] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"and rest conditions it shows the same value as first IF Condition"* - It's not clear to me what you mean by that.  What specifically is is happening when you debug?  What are your runtime values and what do you expect from your comparisons?  The `if` structure in C# works just fine, it's not clear what you're expecting here.

Comment: *"but same code structure doesn't work in C#"* Well no, you don't have the same structure. That would probably be more obvious if the VB code was formatted "properly"

Comment: When i Debug......for this line (First Line)    dRow["Code"].ToString() == "104"  it works fine....but when i go to next or third condition while debugging...it shows the same value  104 and condition remains False.....although it is supppoose to be True

Comment: Your VB code has nested if statements, your C# code does not. So it is a different structure.

Comment: @MalikUsman: How can more than one of those conditions *ever* be true for the same record?  `dRow["Code"].ToString()` can't be both `"104"` *and* `"105"` at the same time.  It's not clear at all what you're describing.

Comment: Let's say i have 3 columns in Database Table  (Code, Name, Active)
and that table have multiple rows.......i want to store each row value in different sessions..............so i can check and use those sessions in different places (According to Code) where i need them.........

Comment: @MalikUsman: Ok, let's say that.  Now, having said that, what in the code you're showing us isn't working as expected?  What is the *actual problem*?

Comment: @MalikUsman You need to post your entire code structure to see how you are iterating over the rows in order to determine if it is working or not. See Marcelo's answer below

Comment: I want to use these sessions in different Places.....Session["101"], Session["102"], Session["103"], Session["104"].........and so on (Assume those code represent each ASP.net Page Code) once use login i will store all those values in different Sessions....and when user is on Page 101 i will check wheather Sesssion["101"] is true or false.......................... So that's why i need to store Row Values to store in Different Sessions......but with Condition...

Answer (score 2):

It's not perfectly clear what you're trying to accomplish, but I suggest you think more about the problem then about "translating".

Is this closer to what you really want to accomplish?

```
//First I'll create an array of every value to be inspected and iterate through it....
foreach (var c in new[] {"104", "105", "106"})
{
    //Then I'll check the current value (considering the value of dRow["Active"]...
    Session[c] = ( ((bool)dRow["Active"]) && (dRow["Code"].ToString() == c) )  //Thanks to @jjwillmc observation
}
```

If you prefer to use only IFs, the VB code translate as follows:

```
If roleRow.Item("Code").ToString() = "101" Then 'Admin Settings
    If roleRow.Item("Active") = True Then Session("101") = True Else Session("101") = False
End If
If roleRow.Item("Code").ToString() = "102" Then 'Summaries / Reports
    If roleRow.Item("Active") = True Then Session("102") = True Else Session("102") = False
End If
If roleRow.Item("Code").ToString() = "103" Then 'Invoices List
    If roleRow.Item("Active") = True Then Session("103") = True Else Session("103") = False
End If
```

turns into:

```
if (roleRow.Item("Code").ToString() == "101") //Admin Settings
{
    if (roleRow.Item("Active")) 
      Session["101"] = true; 
    else 
      Session["101"] = False;
    //Or simply: Session["101"] = (roleRow.Item("Active"));
}
if (roleRow.Item("Code").ToString() == "102") //Summaries / Reports
{
    if (roleRow.Item("Active")) 
      Session["102"] = true; 
    else 
      Session["102"] = false;
    //Or simply: Session["102"] = (roleRow.Item("Active"));
}
if (roleRow.Item("Code").ToString() == "103") //Invoices List
{
    if (roleRow.Item("Active")) 
      Session["103"] = true;
    else 
      Session["103"] = false;
    //Or simply: Session["103"] = (roleRow.Item("Active"));
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I want to use these sessions in different Places.....Session["101"], Session["102"],  Session["103"], Session["104"].........and so on..............
So that's why i need to store Row Values to store in Different Sessions......but with Condition...
for Reference you can also see my VB Code which i posted above.....that works fine in VB.Net.....but same code structure dont' work in C#.

Comment: That code structure does also work in C#. You have to post your entire code so we can see how you iterating over the rows in order to set all those session variables

Comment: @MalikUsman, the code structure using only IFs does work on C# too, probably there's something missing (I'll check your VB code more carefully and try to find it). But consider that the code above (using the foreach) is probably a better algorithm. You can use an array of all the codes you want and it will still work without having to increase the number of IFs.

Comment: This code is actually subtly different as it never sets Session[x] to false if active is false.  I can update after the pending edit, but otherwise I agree - the OP is being very vague.

Comment: I have updated main Question Code with my Read Method ....so you can have better look..........remember i need those multiple SESSIOSN to store multi rows values as above structure.......not evaluate only one condition...........you can suggest better or alternate way....

Comment: @MalikUsman, specially because you will have to evaluate many session values (101, 102, 103, ...) you shouldn't be using IFs. When using IFs you're "hard coding" all the sessions values with their comparisons. The first solution that I posted (using FOREACH) will compare all the values present in the array. That way, you'll only have to change one place to add or remove session codes, or even better, replace that hard coded array with something filled dynamically.

Comment: @MarceloMyara   looks like you converted the VB Code from Online Code Convertor.....i already tried..that it is not working.......it take the first session["101"] = True......but when it comes to Second condition and Thrid condition......it take the values FALSE........although in Table those are True.........it is not working....

Comment: @MalikUsman the code was translated "by hand" (I did not use any automated tool) because it's pretty straightforward... Let me try to understand the scenario that you just mentioned... one sec

Comment: The code is identical.  I do not understand how roleRow.Item("Code").ToString() was ever more than one value....  If Code is 101, it can't also be 102...  Also, @MarceloMyara, you attributed that code fix to the wrong person.  lol

Comment: MalikUsman, I fail to see where the code is not equivalent to the VB provided. Maybe you have a "binding" assumption that is not write? (Can you inspect the session codes values to be sure they're what you think they are?); @TheSoftwareJedi, sorry bout that (I credited JJWillMCs comment above, is there someone else that I failed to mention? lol)

Answer (score -1):

Done....was missing For Loop inside the code...this way it is reading each line and putting for each line value in different SESSION......also before this line
**DataRow dRow;**       you have to declare each SESSION = False as default value....

```
DataRow dRow;
            if (aDT.Rows.Count > 0)
            { 
                for (var i = 0; i <= aDT.Rows.Count -1; i++)
                {                   
                    dRow = aDT.Rows[i];                        

                    if (dRow["Code"].ToString() == "101" && (Boolean)dRow["Active"] == true)
                    {
                        Session["101"] = true;
                    }                    

                    else if (dRow["Code"].ToString() == "102" && (Boolean)dRow["Active"] == true)
                    {
                        Session["102"] = true;
                    }                   

                    else if (dRow["Code"].ToString() == "103" && (Boolean)dRow["Active"] == true)
                    {
                        Session["103"] = true;
                    }
```